# Lambda: DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues

Tags: lambda, nestjs, typeorm, serverless

I deploy Lambda with NestJS & TypeORM, and I got error when I using function:

```
ERROR   (node:9) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

[image]

NOTE: I use VPC to connect MySQL Server.

Please help me. Thank you!